# Login with custom fields with Spring Security UI Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security

Instead of login with username/password  user has to login with emailAddress/password how can I customize registerController?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your Custom Authentication Provider.

Here's an good example: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1090 (by @Burt Beckwith)